# Difference between DECLARE, VARIABLE and DEFINE in PL/SQL

Tags: variables, plsql, declare

i am new to PL/SQL. I am confused with the difference between following.

**DECLARE**
name Varchar2(20);

**VARIABLE**
name Varchar2(20);

**DEFINE** name = 'myname';

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`DECLARE` starts a pl/sql block.

`DEFINE` substitute values.

Regarding `VARIABLE` take a look on [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12050.htm).

Answer (score -1):

please note a syntax bellow for pl/sql block

```
declare
 -- you can declare variable here like
v_name     varchar2(50); -- declaration of variable
v_app_name varchar2(10):= 'oracle_app'; -- declaration and definition of veriable 
begin
  -- business logic goes here...
--exception section....
end;
```

**declare** : start of pl/sql block.

**variable** : is name of variable used for storing intermediate/computation value.

**Define** : The DEFINE and UNDEFINE commands allow you to explicitly create and 
         delete user variables. DEFINE creates a variable and assigns it an 
         initial value. DEFINE also lets you list all currently defined user 
         variables with their values. these are mainly used in sql script; eg to store table_space name which can be used for creating table

Comment: No explanation for the question. Author of the question perhaps doesn't have problem to declare variable using DECLARE...